# what would cause SSH connection refused but not refuse an immediate subsequent attempt?

Tags: ssh, networking

- Linux Server(s) running RHEL 7.9 and Windows 10 pc's
- All on LAN, through Cisco switch
- from win10 pc I open putty.exe and ssh to server A via server A's ip address
- putty immediately responds with connection refused
- as fast as I can use the mouse I open another putty window and connect to server A and it works.
- this happens consistently; after some elapsed time (haven't specifically measured)  you always have to putty twice to this one linux server but it doesn't happen to other identically configured linux servers on the LAN.

**what would cause such a thing?**

I have pretty much narrowed down all my problems to using this one specific cisco switch,

I've proven I do not have any problems any which way if I simply take this one switch out of the equation... problems which include the `scp` of a single 60gb tar file that will go for 2-5 minutes then abruptly end with `ssh port 22 broken pipe` and mention of `packet_write_wait` if this has any relevance, and also not being able to SSH from linux server A through this switch to linux server B getting connection refused **but** if I first just initiate an SSH connection from B to A, then SSH from A to B will work immediately after.  But then 1+ hours later the SSH from A->B results in connection refused again until I initiate an SSH from B->A.

Any further troubleshooting methods in addition to a logical explanation on anything mentioned welcomed.

Comment: Installing wireguard on the PC and capturing all traffic to server A's address would be interesting. The Server A -> Server B failing until you have done a Server B -> Server A, which then works for an hour sounds like an ARP problem. Are any of the ports on the switch configured for VLANs? Are there any MAC filters? Does plugging Server A into a different port make the symptoms change? Any chance there could be a second machine with the same address as Server A? Always worth asking if it is worth your time to fix this rather than just replacing the switch?

Comment: @icarus Wireshark presumably ;-)

Comment: Yes,I did mean wireshark. I was going to say tcpdump, changed it as it was a PC probably running windows as the OP said he was using putty and got it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Does the etherswitch have a load balancing feature enabled that sends your connections to a different computer/device at first, but your attempts then cause the switch to resume routing to your intended server?  It's a little far-fetched a scenario, but it sounds like you've already checked the most likely causes.

Comment: Also look in the server's logfiles for complaints that another machine has the server's IP address.  If two computers are each responding to ARPs for the same IP address, you can see symptoms similar to the ones you describe.  The complaint in the logfile will give the ethernet MAC address of the other server, which the switch can resolve to the physical port number, and through the cable to the other machine/device.  This is a more likely scenario than my previous comment about load balancing.

Comment: thanks... sorry i know next to nothing about the switch other than it's a cisco using SFP's to give rj45 copper connection over cat6 cable; I'll post its model number when i can

Comment: How many switches are there in total? If there is more than 1 can you indicate which of "Server A", "Server B" and "PC" are connected to the same switch? We may be being asked to debug a switch to switch problem, rather than a Server A problem.